# Obtaining IP addresses in Bittorrent

Tags: python, language-agnostic, prototype, p2p, bittorrent

I am trying to get a list of IP addresses serving or downloading a file. What I did was to contact a tracker like openbittorrent.com to get the following (as part of the scrape file):

```
B%00%00%0C%5F%B1%B1l%CAGa%84S%CB%B0%9BG%84%3BE:0:1
```

Now, the long string in the beginning is the info hash. As a next step, I did this:

```
http://tracker.sometracker.com/announce?info_hash=B%00%00%0C%5F%B1%B1l%CAGa%84S%CB%B0%9BG%84%3BE
```

It gave me back the following. So far so good. The message contained this:

```
d8:completei0e10:downloadedi0e10:incompletei2e8:intervali1931e12:min intervali965e5:peers12:U���ٿ��ӣǣ^@^@e
```

Can someone tell me what should I be doing after this to get the IP addresses currently serving the file or downloading it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a torrent file, that's an announce response. They're both bencode (use [bencode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitTorrent-bencode) to decode them), but the announce response contains only peer information. That's not enough information to be able to download the contents of the torrent: to do that you will need the torrent file itself.

The `peers` member of the bencoded dictionary contains groups of 6 bytes which you can unpack with `struct`. First four bytes are the IP address, followed by two bytes for the port. This is a compact announce response, which is common (but IPv4 only, obviously). You may also see non-compact responses which give you a transparent dictionary.

Many trackers today won't talk to you with the non-specific scrape announce you're sending, or the initial announce request that doesn't include `compact`, `port` or `event`. You should probably read over [the protocol](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) a bit before going further.